# Where to change password validation message?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

When customers attempt to create an account they are currently seeing "Please enter 7 or more characters, using both numeric and alphabetic." as the password validation error message.

I have already changed the validation via regular expression to 8 or more characters containing at least 1 number, 1 uppercase, and 1 lowercase letter.

So, Where can I change the error message to match the criteria?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: which file you changed and please tell the file path also?

Answer (score 0):

Please open this file `your_app_root_folder/lib/web/mage/validation.js` .
In this file search for `Please enter 7 or more characters, using both numeric and alphabetic.` 
Then change this error message and do setup:upgrade,compile, deploy etc and all other general steps.

 This solution worked for me also and I hope it will work for you also. 
 And also in this javascript function `validate-admin-password` you can also edit the password length to 8. 
**Edit - Adding more files for your reference** 
I am Sharing some more files which may be useful you may check them -

1. /lib/web/i18n/en_US.csv
2. lib/web/prototype/validation.js
3. vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/i18n/en_US.csv
4. vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation.js
5. vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/prototype/validation.js
6. vendor/magento/module-ui/i18n/en_US.csv
7. vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: I edited my answer, shared more files you may check your string there.

Comment: I have changed all these files but still no change.